# Polymoprhism - subclasses sharing of baseclass private members

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Why doesnt the subclasses share the same private membervariable in the superclass using polymoprhism? There are only one instance of the baseclass and if SubA is setting the private member through a mutator - why then cannot SubB access this value. How would it look like if I want the subclasses to share the same private member?

```
 #include <iostream>
class Super {

   private:
     int cnt;
   public:
     int getCnt() {
        return cnt;
     }
     void setCnt(int cnt) {
        this->cnt = cnt;
     }
};

class SubA: public Super {

};

class SubB: public Super {

};

int main() {

  Super *super;
  SubA a;
  SubB b;

  super = &a;
  super->setCnt(10);
  super = &b;
  std::cout << super->getCnt() << std::endl;
  super = &a;
  std::cout << super->getCnt() << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
-8589546555 (garbage)
10
```

Comment: b is not initialised. So it is producing a garbage value

Answer (score 5):

> There are only one instance of the baseclass and if SubA

That is wrong. `a` and `b` are *different objects*. They each have an instance of an `A` sub object. You have not set `cnt` in `b`, so it is no surprise that looking at it gives you a garbage value, because reading from an uninitialized object is *undefined behaviour*.

> How would it look like if I want the subclasses to share the same private member?

You could give the base class a `static` data member. That means all instances of `A` would share the same member.

Comment: my question is not about garbagevalue - I understand that already - just why a and b have different instances.

Comment: @java You're not asking *why* they have different instances. You're saying they don't, and I'm telling you they do, because that is the way the language is designed. Imagine the mess if every object shared a base sub-object with all instances of its type!

Comment: @java: To achieve what you want, you can make use of a static class variable in class Super

Comment: No, I say, static class variable: like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable)

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesnt the subclasses share the same private membervariable in the superclass using polymoprhism?

Polymorphism has nothing to do with how data is embedded in classes; (run-time) polymorphism is only relevant to `virtual` dispatch and Run-Time Type Information (RTTI) for `dynamic_cast` and `type_info`.

If you imagine your `a` and `b` objects on the stack, their memory layout can be illustrated like this:

```
A:[[Super: int cnt;]A-specific fields (if there were any)]
B:[[Super: int cnt;]B-specific fields (if there were any)]
```

In effect, `class A : public Super` is saying "I may want to extend 'Super', optionally appending my own data members to those in `Super`, possibly adding further functions / overriding `virtual` ones".

> There are only one instance of the baseclass and if `SubA` is setting the private member through a mutator - why then cannot `SubB` access this value.

This is wrong... each sub class embeds *its own* instance of the super class.

> How would it look like if I want the subclasses to share the same private member?

Well, there are lots of ways in which you could orchestrate that:

- You could have the subclasses hold pointers to a `Data` object into which you move the superclass's data you want shared, then you'd need a way to initialise the `Data` object and make it known to all the subclass instances you want to share it.
- You could make the superclass data `static`, which means a single copy of each `static` variable will be shared by all instances of the superclass, whether embedded in subclasses or not.